# What simpler mail server can I use instead of postfix?

Tags: mail-server

I have a home server which needs a mail server for error messages, mostly.

I used postfix but I find the features/complexity compromises not optimal for my home server: there are tens of lines to check/configure, stunnel to install for TLS, ...

What simpler mail server with TLS support can I use, that is also packaged by Canonical? I'm going to only use an external relay server provided by my provider.

Comment: Why do you use a mailer for system notifications?  Mailers are complex because they were built for another purpose - general mail.  For system notifications only you can replace sendmail with a batch file 30 lines in length - no need for a server.  That batch file can open a connection your provider and send mail via a call to python "sendmail".  Or you can call an API - lots of companies offer that for free now.

Comment: @CraigHicks I see you posted the script but it was downvoted because OT for this question (I got it, thanks, even if it involves more work than I expected based on the question I asked). I suggest asking a question specifically for your script and then answer yourself with the same post you deleted, because it could be quite useful to many people.

Comment: It was OT, that why I deleted it.  Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690965/a-simple-smtp-server-in-python) about minimalist self-"coded" servers and plain senders.  All SMTP, since your provider will forward for you.  Good luck in whatever you choose!

Comment: See also a more recent and extensive set of options, including **`msmtp`**, at [Lightweight outgoing SMTP server - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/lightweight-outgoing-smtp-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple relay-only mail transport agent is `nullmailer`.

There is a good configuration guide here: http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/nullmailer/

That configuration guide is old enough that it omits one important configuration file: `/etc/nullmailer/allmailfrom`. Put just the email address you want the mail to be sent **From** in there. This helps tremendously when configuring various applications to send mail.

Comment: That web site suggests installing the package from source, but that means you won't get security updates etc.  Surely here on AskUbuntu we should recommend using `sudo apt get nullmailer`?

Comment: I personally used your method to install it.  Actually by the time I got to the guide, I had installed it already, and was looking for config help. I didn't even look at the install part.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But have they fixed the nasty "show your password to all local users" security bug referred to there? Who wrote this thing?

Comment: No idea. But when I ran screaming from Postfix, it was a godsend.

Comment: Something simpler than postfix is good. I see lots of recommendations for msmtp e.g. documented here in ways that make me think they were more security-conscious: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Msmtp

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that.

Comment: On Ubuntu, you should use the package, but in other cases (*cough* Debian *cough*), you should install from source so you can get TLS support, which is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

- install **msmtp** and **msmtp-mta**
- when using cron , [you might take a look here to have a real from header](https://gitlab.com/the-foundation/msmtp-cron-sendmail)

example **/etc/msmprc**

```
#logfile   /var/log/mail.log
aliases               /etc/aliases.msmtp

#user 
#password 
# Use startTLS on port 587
port 587
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

host mailserver.net
from Sender Name <user@maildomain.com>
auth on
#auth plain
#auth scram-sha-1

user user@maildomain.com
password YourUnGuessueAblePass

# Set a default account
#account default : outlook
```

---

example    **/etc/aliases.msmtp**

```
mailer-daemon: user@maildomain.com
postmaster: user@maildomain.com
nobody: user@maildomain.com
hostmaster: user@maildomain.com
usenet: user@maildomain.com
news: user@maildomain.com
webmaster: user@maildomain.com
www: user@maildomain.com
ftp: user@maildomain.com
abuse: user@maildomain.com
noc: user@maildomain.com
security: user@maildomain.com

# Send root to Joe and Jane
root: user@maildomain.com

# Send everything else to admin
default: user@maildomain.com
```