# Send mail notification Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: server, email, 18.10, smtp

I've set up unattended upgrades, and wish to receive an email on every update run to make sure it's running. For whatever reason, ssmtp isn't installing so isn't an option.

How do I configure my server to use an external smtp server that uses login and ssl/tls security?

(I want to send from "noreply@example.com" on mail.example.com:465.)

No,  not asking about broken package fixing since I have default repository already. I'm asking if there's an alternative to ssmtp

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on clean 18.10 installation. Check your repositories. So it is possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: I have default repository

Comment: @karel I'm also asking for an alternative to ssmtp. The question isn't asking for a solution to the broken package

Comment: Then you should remove the extraneous content and simply ask about any way to send mail through a smarthost other than ssmtp. (Hint: all MTAs can do this )

Comment: I can't seem to find one that will let me configure it to solely use an external smtp server

Comment: Nullmailer. I can't post an answer now but I have before. Search this site for nullmailer.

Comment: See this question for an answer about simple mail systems: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124620/what-simpler-mail-server-can-i-use-instead-of-postfix/1124624