# Can Admin Notifications by Email be Set up without an FQDN?

Tags: email, notification, postfix

I am attempting to migrate a personal/family server from AWS to a local Ubuntu 18.04 server. I want to experiment with this local server for possibly months before cancelling the AWS server, so prefer minimal or no changes to the existing DNS records, etc.

I would like to get admin notifications sent to me by the new/experimental server for various events... Security updates failing to auto-install, etc. I don't need to receive mail or do anything other than enabling automated system messages to my own email address.

Finally, I understand that prior versions of Ubuntu Server came with mail sending ability configured and working out-of-the-box. So am confused by tutorials and examples that require creating DNS records and other steps that would not have been done by the Ubuntu installer.

*Is an FQDN with 'A' and 'ptr' records strictly required for admin notification emails to be reliably delivered?*

In any event, I'm looking for the simplest way to get this send-only email working. I am using gmail with an app password, and am considering the method described here:
   https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/postfix-send-only-multiple-domains-ubuntu

I stopped to ask this question because of evidence in other posts that there may be much simpler, lighter-weight ways to support my limited needs. But I'm not finding actual instructions for how to accomplish them.

*Is there a simpler way to enable these notification emails?*

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does your "experimental sever" use permanent/fixed IP address?

Comment: See my answer about the simple mail relay system `nullmailer` here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1124624/243321

Comment: Re: "Fixed IP?" Tecnically, no. But it changes so rarely that I can just update config if/when it does. It is unlikely to change between now and the time that I am done experimenting.

When done with experiments and properly deployed, it will have a static IP.