# Installing Apache Mod_Evasive without installing Postfix

Tags: apt, apache2, postfix

On Ubuntu 18 I'd like to install Apache Mod_Evasive but without installing Postfix.

In fact, I'm using `msmtp` as a simple way of connecting to a remote smtp server to send out mail, so I don't need a fully fledged mail server.

I don't really care that Mod_Evasive won't be able to send email notifications, since when an IP is blocked I can write a simple script to send an email via msmtp instead.

I tried:

`apt install libapache2-mod-evasive postfix- bsd-mailx-`

Whilst this avoided installing Postfix and BSD-Mailx, it just tried to install a bunch of other mail dependancies instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the simple relay-only mail transport agent `nullmailer` instead and that will satisfy the dependency.

See my answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/1124624/243321, I find `nullmailer` extremely useful.