postfix smtp relay with basic auth
OS version: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I need to deploy a simple smtp relay that supports basic auth (client side)
I have problems with SASL, even if the user and password are correct I get this error:
SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure, sasl_username=relay@ub1 

The user seems to exist
prx@ub1:~$ sudo sasldblistusers2
relay@ub1: userPassword

If I try credentials in this way, I get authentication failed
prx@ub1:~$ sudo testsaslauthd -u relay@ub1 -p pwd
0: NO "authentication failed"

If I try in this way I get Success
prx@ub1:~$ sudo testsaslauthd -u relay -p pwd
0: OK "Success."

main.cf
    See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6

# relay
relayhost = relay.external.internet


smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# Log debug
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1


Where I'm wrong?

What version of Ubuntu are you using? Please edit the question and add this info. The only OS mention in your question is Debian and that is off topic on this Ubuntu only site.

Consider using nullmailer instead https://askubuntu.com/a/1124624/243321
